# Can a Picker signal my MV when it gains focus?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

This doesn't work:

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding myList}" Title="Select one" SelectedItem="{Binding myItem}">
    <Picker.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger Event="Focused">
            <local:FocusedTriggerAction />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Picker.Triggers>
    <Picker.ItemDisplayBinding>
        <Binding Path="FullName"/>
    </Picker.ItemDisplayBinding>
</Picker>
```

I do not think that "Focused" is an acceptable Trigger for a Picker.  Any workarounds available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With touch based input the color change in the example below seems to have effect in a simulator when the picker list is shown.

```
<Picker Title="Select" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item}">
  <Picker.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger Event="Focused">
      <local:FocusTriggerAction TextColor="Green" />
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger Event="Unfocused">
      <local:FocusTriggerAction TextColor="Default" />
    </EventTrigger>
  </Picker.Triggers>
</Picker>
```

[`EventTrigger`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/triggers/#Event_Triggers):

```
public class FocusTriggerAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    public Color TextColor { get; set; }

    protected override void Invoke(VisualElement visual)
    {
        var view = visual as Picker;
        if (view == null) return;
        if (TextColor != null) view.TextColor = TextColor;
        Debug.WriteLine(visual.IsFocused ? "Focused" : "Unfocused");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post.  It helped me figure out why I kept getting errors on the Focused event.  When I switched the trigger from the Entry control to the Picker, I forgot to change the 'Entry' parts of the EventTrigger code to 'Picker'.